# If $\int_0^3 f(x)dx=8 $, what are the values of related integrals such as $\int_0^3 2f(x)dx$ and $\int_0^3 (f(x)+2)dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Thank you so much for the help/edits! I'm new to the site.

I'm a high school senior going in to IB Math HL, I took AP Calculus BC last year, and this is one of the problems on my summer packet. I figured out part (i) (I got 16, i think that is correct.) I also solved part ii and got 14. But I am stuck on the last question part b.

I thought that maybe since the graph is shifted 2 right, i would move the limits of integration also right 2, but I don't think that would quite work.

Any advice on solving? thank you! (I put in **bold** the answers that I put in and didn't come with the original problem. )

Let $f(x)$ be a function such that $\int_0^3 f(x)dx=8 $

(a) Deduce the value of

(i) $\int_0^3 2f(x)dx= \mathbf{16} $

(ii) $\int_0^3 (f(x)+2)dx= \mathbf{14} $

(b) If $\int_c^d f(x — 2)dx = 8$ , write down the value of c and of d.

Its easier to see it here: Its question 7. 
http://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http%3A%2F%2Fpeabodyte.ism-online.org%2Ffiles%2F2010%2F02%2FIntegration-Worksheet.doc

Thank you so much for your help! Much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange! Please try and format your question properly so that it makes it easier for others to answer. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a guide for formatting equations. Also show us what you have tried and your thoughts on the problem so we can help you more effectively.

Comment: Use the linearity properties of the integral.

Comment: But im not sure if i can split up the integral into 2 since the -2 is in f(x)?

Comment: if it were F(x) -2 I would split it but it says f(x-2) so does that make it different? Thank you for your comment

Comment: Have you learned about change of variables/change of limits of integration?

Comment: You have to make u = x-2. So, du = dx.
integral of f(x-2)dx = integral of f(u)du.
But, the limits from a to b becomes a-2 and b-2 (because u = x-2).

So, integral from c to d of f(x-2)dx = integral from c-2 to d-2 of f(u)du.

Comment: I think a particular function graph will help: http://i.imgur.com/6bxKqA2.png

Answer (score 1):

The first 2 items are correct.
With this image you can use intuitivity to solve the third one:

[image: graph]

Yes, $f(x-2)$ and $f(x) - 2$ are different and have different ways to solve.

From substitution, if you make $u = x-2$, you will have $du=dx$ and then:
$$\int f(x-2)dx = \int f(u)du$$.

But if $x=c$ and $x=d$, then $u=c-2$ and $u=d-2$.

So $$\int_c^d f(x-2)dx = \int_{c-2}^{d-2} f(u)du = 8$$

You can go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding part $(b)$, there is one pair of values, $c$ and $d$ that will work for all such $f$, but there are functions for which there are infinitely many such pairs.

A trivial example is the constant function $f(x) = 8$.

Other examples can be constructed using periodic functions.

For instance, we can find a sinusoidal function of period $2$, whose integral on $[0,3]$ is $8$.

Answer (score 0):

$$I_1=\int_0^3f(x)dx=8$$
$$I_2=\int_0^32f(x)dx=2\int_0^3f(x)dx=16$$
$$I_3=\int_0^3\left[f(x)+2\right]dx=I_1+\left[2x\right]_0^3=8+6=14$$